# Moving cell values and deleting rows

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, rows, paste

I need to move some data but my current code (started with vba some weeks, so please be benevolent :) ) is super-slow.

Can you give me some advices?

I want to to from this...

[image: I want to to from this...]

...to this...

[image: ...to this...]

...and then this.

[image: ...and then this.]

```
Do While Not Listado.Cells(rowquery, colquery) = ""
        Listado.Cells(rowquery, colquery).Offset(0, 2) = Listado.Cells(rowquery, colquery).Offset(1, 1)
        Listado.Cells(rowquery, colquery).Offset(0, 3) = Listado.Cells(rowquery, colquery).Offset(2, 1)
        Listado.Cells(rowquery, colquery).Offset(1, 1).Clear
        Listado.Cells(rowquery, colquery).Offset(2, 1).Clear
        rowquery = rowquery + 3
Loop
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's slow because you are continually accessing the worksheet. There may even be formulas that reference the cells being moved and cleared.

Work within variant arrays and dump the data back to the worksshet then remove duplicates on the first column.

```
dim i as long, arr as variant

arr = Listado.databodyrange.value2

for i=lbound(arr, 1) to ubound(arr, 1) step 3
    arr(i, 3) = arr(i+1, 2)
    arr(i, 4) = arr(i+2, 2)
    arr(i+1, 2) = vbnullstring
    arr(i+2, 2) = vbnullstring
next i

Listado.databodyrange = arr
```

Comment: I was able to adapt your code to my needs. Thank you so much!